# How to open angular mat-menu on double click?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I would like to open mat-menu when trigger element is clicked two times.
Currently it opens after first click and closes after the other.

```
<div [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">Trigger element</div>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Tried adding (dblclick)="menuTrigger.OpenMenu()" to trigger element.

```
<div (dblclick)="menuTrigger.OpenMenu()" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">Trigger element</div>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Tried adding (focus)="menuTrigger.openMenu()" to trigger element.

```
<div (focus)="menuTrigger.openMenu()" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">Trigger element</div>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Tried opening from component.ts

```
export class ExampleComponent {
  @ViewChild('menuTrigger') trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  open() {
    this.trigger.openMenu()
  }
```

```
<div (dblclick)="open()" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">Trigger element</div>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Tried removing click handler from trigger element

```
export class ExampleComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('menuTrigger') trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.trigger._handleClick = ()=>{}
  }
```

Comment: For this special use-case try to open menu pragmatically instead from template. Trigger toggling function on double click

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
<div [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (dblclick)="someMethod()">Trigger element</div>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

and then in controller

```
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  someMethod() {
    this.trigger.openMenu();
  }
}
```

Hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: Tried this before as well. Nope.